# Elasticsearch filter objects

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I apply the following query, filter to this dataset?

Query:  term = Python

Filter: Salary | range (1, 200000)

*note I don't want to apply the filter to "float_value". In my case Salary is a value of an object that has float_value as it's sibling.

Is this even possible?

```
{
_index  : "platform",
_type   : "documents",
_id     : "532a1cff54f4c233b3bc3ed5"",
_version: 1,
_score  : 1,
_source : {
    fields: [
        {
            name        : "salary",
            float_value : 120000
        },
        {
            name        : "bonus",
            float_value : 1000
        },
        {
            name        : "Programming Skills",
            text_value  : "Java, Ruby, Python, node.js"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: in which field the salary value stored??

Comment: the field name is: float_value

Comment: without filtering particular fields ,i don think you can get the result..may i know what is the scenario ans why you don want to apply filter on float_value feild..!

Comment: There are multiple fields named float_value in filed objects. If I use that to filter, I can't specify which object I want the filter to be applied. e.g. Salary and not the bonus.

Comment: jus add another filter that name : "salary". i wanna tell you one thing you can use like salary:salary value,bonous:1000 lik this..its json format.. easy to use..if you change it.. u can easliy do it..

Comment: I don't think that would work. Because the filter on "float_value" lets say 0, 10000 could get applied to another field and the filter on "name" gets matched as it exists. I also, can't change the format and mappings...

Comment: Am sorry its difficult to create such a query..Better change the schema of doc.. then it easy to query..!